# Fetching JASON API using PHP

Tags: php, json

here is a PHP code I am using to fetch pollution data:

```
<?php
$pol = file_get_contents('https://api.openaq.org/v1/latest/?city=Delhi');
$poldata = json_decode($pol);
$polres = $poldata->results;
$polcnt = count($polres);
$pm10 = 0;
$cnt = 0;

for ($x=0; $x < $polcnt; $x++){
    foreach ($polres[$x] as $v){
        $m = $v->measurements;
        $z = count($m);
        foreach ($m as $k){
        for ($y = 0; $y < $z; $y++){
            if($k->parameter == "pm10"){
              $pm10 += $k->value;
              $cnt++;
            }
        }
    }}
}
$pm10 /= $cnt;
$tst = "Test";

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><?php echo $tst; ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $pm10; ?></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am getting following warning messages:

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /home2/mridulmishra/public_html/delpollution/index.php on line 12

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home2/mridulmishra/public_html/delpollution/index.php on line 13

And it's not working. Just showing NAN at the end. Could anyone help, please!

Comment: Have you done a `var_dump` of `$poldata`?

Comment: try to var_dump $polres, i think it's not an array